# Count number of changes for each unique variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a long dataframe with multiple subjects (id), trial numbers and responses. I want to know how many times Response changed for each subject. The possible responses are 1 and 0. 
So the new column "change" should be the same number for each row of the same subject.

Right now I am able to get the number of changes in Response for the entire dataframe, and not specific to each subject (id).

How can I get this number so be specific to the ID? I thought `group_by()` would do this but it does not.

Headers of HNPS_df2: id     Trial_Num     Response 
Where each ID has a row for each trial

`HNPS_df2 <- HNPS_df2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(change = cumsum(ifelse(Response != lag(Response) | is.na(lag(Response)), 1, 0)))`

Any ideas?
I am new to this to detailed explanations would be great and sorry if this is a repeat!

EDIT
I am not getting an error, I am just not getting what I want ha. 
Here is a shortened version of my data frame

```
df <- data_frame(
        id = c(500, 500, 500, 501, 501, 501, 502, 502, 502), 
        trial_num = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
        Response = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0))
```

what I want it to look like after would be to add a column that has the number of changes

```
change <- data_frame(change = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

But when I use this code:

```
df <- df %>% 
         group_by(id) %>% 
         mutate(changeD = cumsum(ifelse(Response!= lag(Response) | is.na(lag(Response)), 1, 0)))
```

the counter does not "restart" at each new id number

Comment: Hi Natalie, can you make this a minimum reproducible example so we can cut and paste the code into our R sessions, reproduce the error you are getting, and work with the code directly to provide you insights? Thanks :)

Comment: thank you for your help! and for being nice haha. I am not getting an error, the "change" column I am getting is count the number of changes as you go down the entire Response column

Comment: Why does `id` 502 show 2 changes? `c(1, 1, 0)` is only one change right?

Comment: you are right RyanD... I am in over my head here! Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I create a temporary variable `R2`, which replaces `NA`s in `Response` with a value I know `Response` doesn't take. Then since `R2` has no `NA` values, I can just look at `diff(R2)`. If the `diff` is not `0`, there is a change, so `sum(diff(R2) != 0)` equals the number of changes.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(
        id = c(500, 500, 500, 501, 501, 501, 502, 502, 502), 
        trial_num = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
        Response = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0))


df %>% 
  mutate(R2 = replace(Response, is.na(Response), max(Response, na.rm = T) + 1)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(change = sum(diff(R2) != 0)) %>% 
  select(-R2)
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
# # Groups:   id [3]
#      id trial_num Response change
#   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>
# 1   500         1        0      0
# 2   500         2        0      0
# 3   500         3        0      0
# 4   501         1        1      1
# 5   501         2        0      1
# 6   501         3        0      1
# 7   502         1        1      1
# 8   502         2        1      1
# 9   502         3        0      1
```

The `diff` function takes the difference between each element and the next one. For example

```
diff(c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10))
# [1] 1 2 1 5
```

base R version

```
df$change <- 
  with(df, rep(tapply({r <- Response
                      replace(r, is.na(r), max(r, na.rm = T) + 1)}
                      , id
                      , function(x) sum(diff(x) != 0))
              , lengths(split(id, id))))
```

Comment: Hmm that is not working for me for some reason. My "change" column is all 4s.

Comment: is there a package other than tidyverse that is necessary?

Comment: you should only need `dplyr`, which is part of `tidyverse`. I ran the code in my answer on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ and it shows the given output, so it should work for you if you restart your R session.

Comment: added a base R version

Comment: RyanD you are the best!!! Thank you so much for helping me out and taking the time to explain what you did.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested, this is straightforward with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Change := max(rleid(Response) - 1), by = id][, .(Change)]

   Change
1:      0
2:      0
3:      0
4:      1
5:      1
6:      1
7:      1
8:      1
9:      1
```

You can also incorporate this into `dplyr`:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(Change = max(rleid(Response) - 1)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% select(Change)

  Change
   <dbl>
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      1
5      1
6      1
7      1
8      1
9      1
```

Something like that would also work without `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(Change = Response != lag(Response),
                               Change = ifelse(is.na(Change), FALSE, Change),
                               Change = max(cumsum(Change))) %>% ungroup() %>% select(Change)

  Change
   <int>
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      1
5      1
6      1
7      1
8      1
9      1
```